# Undeclared identifier C++

Tags: c++

I'm making an calculator for exercise, and what you eat. I need to make a pre-defined list of five foods, but the list keeps stating 'undeclared identifier'. I worked with it a few days ago, where it worked, but now i doesn't.

The problem occurs at the `Insert();` in the main function
`insert(head, "Carrot", 100);`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct node
{
    string name;
    int eatCalories;
    int number;
    node *next;

};

bool isEmpty(node *head);
char menu();
void insertAsFirstElement(node *&head, node *&last, string name, int eatCalories);
void insert(node *&head, node *&last, string name, int eatCalories);
void showList(node *current);


bool isEmpty(node *head)
{
    if(head == NULL)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

char menu()
{
    char choice;

    cout << "Menu\n";
    cout << "1. Tilføj madvarer til listen\n";
    cout << "2. Vis listen af madvarer\n";
    cout << "3. Opdater vægt\n";
    cout << "4. Indtast madvarer\n";
    cout << "5. Indtast dagens motion\n";
    cout << "6. Exit program \n";

    cin >> choice;

    return choice;

}

void insertAsFirstElement(node *&head, node *&last, string name, int eatCalories)
{
    node *temp = new node;
    temp->name = name;
    temp->eatCalories = eatCalories;
    temp->next = NULL;
    head = temp;
    last = temp;
}

void insert(node *&head, node *&last, string name, int eatCalories)
{
    if(isEmpty(head))
        insertAsFirstElement(head, last, name, eatCalories);
    else
    {
        node *temp = new node;
        temp->name = name;
        temp->eatCalories = eatCalories;
        temp->next = NULL;
        last->next = temp;
        last = temp;
    }

}
void showList(node *current)
{

    if(isEmpty(current))
        cout << "The list of foods is empty\n";
    else
    {
        cout << "The list of foods contain: \n";
        int  number = 0;

        while(current != NULL)
        {
            ++number;
            cout << number << " " << current->name << " " << current->eatCalories << " calories" << endl;

            current = current->next;


        }
    }


}
node* subtractCalories(node *head)
{
    int choice;
    showList(head);
    cout << "Vælg nummer fra listen\n";
    cin >> choice;

    int number = 1;
    node *current = head;
    while (current != NULL && choice != number)
    {
        ++number;
        current = current->next;
    }
    cout << "Du har valgt: " << current->name << endl;
    return current;
}





int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    insert(head, "Carrot", 100);
    insert(head, "Banana", 50);
    insert(head, "Apple", 20);
    insert(head, "Pineapple", 30);
    insert(head, "Biscuit", 40);


    string motion;
    double vaegt;
    double kalorie;

    int answer = 1;
    float minutesExerciseInHour;
    int quotes = 0;
    float caloriesBurned;

    cout << "Velkommen til kalorieberegneren!\n";
    cout << "Indtast dit kalorieindtag for i dag, så vi kan komme igang med at regne på det\n";
    cin >> kalorie;
    cout << "Hvad er din nuvaerende veagt?\n";
    cin >> vaegt;

    node *head = NULL;
    node *last = NULL;
    node *current;
    char choice;
    int eatCalories;
    string name;

    do{

        choice = menu();
        switch(choice)
        {
            case '1':
                cout << "Indtast navn:";
                cin >> name;
                cout << "Indtast nummer:";
                cin >> eatCalories;

                insert(head, last, name, eatCalories);
                break;

            case '2': showList(head);
                break;

            case '3': cout << "Hvad er din vægt?\n";
                cin >> vaegt;
                cout << "Din vægt er blevet opdateret til: \n";
                cout << vaegt << endl;
                break;

            case '4':
                cout << endl << "You need to consume " << kalorie << " calories today!" << endl << endl;
                current = subtractCalories(head);
                kalorie = kalorie-current->eatCalories;
                cout << endl << "You need to eat " << kalorie<< " calories more today!" << endl;
                break;

            case '5':

                do
                {
                    cout << "Hvor mange minutter motion? (angiv i timer)\n";
                    cin >> minutesExerciseInHour;
                    cout << "Hvilken type motion?" <<endl;
                    cout << "1. Løb" <<endl;
                    cout << "2. Svømning" <<endl;
                    cout << "3. Cykling" <<endl;
                    cin >> quotes;

                    switch(quotes)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            caloriesBurned = vaegt*7.5*minutesExerciseInHour;
                            cout << "Du har forbrændt: " << caloriesBurned << "kalorier\n";
                            kalorie = kalorie + caloriesBurned;
                            cout << "Du har: " << kalorie << " tilbage for i dag\n";
                            break;

                        case 2:
                            caloriesBurned = vaegt*7*minutesExerciseInHour;
                            cout << "Du har forbrændt: " << caloriesBurned << "kalorier\n";
                            kalorie = kalorie + caloriesBurned;
                            cout << "Du har: " << kalorie << " tilbage for i dag\n";
                            break;

                        case 3:
                            caloriesBurned = vaegt*6*minutesExerciseInHour;
                            cout << "Du har forbrændt: " << caloriesBurned << "kalorier\n";
                            kalorie = kalorie + caloriesBurned;
                            cout << "Du har: " << kalorie << " tilbage for i dag\n";
                            break;

                        default: cout << "What is that?";
                    }
                }

                while (answer != 1);

            default: cout << "System exit\n";
        }
    }while(choice != '5');


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Count the parameters in both the call and the function.

Comment: You haven't declared `head`. I guess you want `node * head = 0;` at the start of `main`.

Comment: The  `*&`. The horrors.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to encapsulate your list functions in a class?

Comment: I declared the node *head = 0; at the main start, after that the problem was 'no matching function for call to insert' ?

Comment: @EmilSkovgaard _`'no matching function for call to insert'`_ Look at the function signature, it requires four parameters, but you pass only three.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use identifier `head` before its declaration

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    insert(head, "Carrot", 100);
    insert(head, "Banana", 50);
    insert(head, "Apple", 20);
    insert(head, "Pineapple", 30);
    insert(head, "Biscuit", 40);

//...


    node *head = NULL;
    node *last = NULL;
    node *current;
    char choice;
    int eatCalories;
    string name;
```

Thus when function `insert` is called in the very beginning of main the compiler does not know yet what is `head`.

Also take into account that the function declared with four parameters

```
void insert(node *&head, node *&last, string name, int eatCalories);
```

but you are calling it in main with three arguments

```
    insert(head, "Carrot", 100);
    insert(head, "Banana", 50);
    insert(head, "Apple", 20);
    insert(head, "Pineapple", 30);
    insert(head, "Biscuit", 40);
```

Comment: I inserted after the *head call, but then it states "no matching function for call to insert"... ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help everyone. The solution was given by πάντα ῥεῖ and Vlad from Moscow. I only gave three parameters, and it required four.